# How do I get started with the non-supported gyroscope?

Tags: ros, imu, driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, my project was given a Cruizcore XG1010 gyroscope to improve the robot Odometry , may i know how should i get started with it? I managed to find the part of the code from:
http://svn.openrobotino.org/trunk/openrobotino1/daemons/gyrod/

The product detail:
http://www.cruizcore.com/e_p_robot03.html

Currently the robot I am using is able to use joystick to move around. I am quite new to ros and linux.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36672/how-do-i-get-started-with-the-non-supported-gyroscope?/) by [halfstopper](https://answers.ros.org/users/2417/halfstopper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since you are new to ROS, it would be best you start from the tutorials, especially [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29)

Once you know how to write a publisher, use the code that you have to grab data off your gyro. Put this data into the correct format for publishing.

You can also refer to codes for other sensor nodes eg http://www.ros.org/wiki/lse_xsens_mti to see what is published and how to publish it

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3